# want to filter an array

Tags: reactjs, filter

I want to get an array with filtered values.
My arrays are like,

```
let arr=[{name:'trt,tet', id:5},{name:td, id:25},{name:fxg, id:1},{name:fs, id:4},{name:ste, id:41}]
```

&

```
let arr1 =[{data:fxg, addr:po 87987},{data:tert, addr:po8798fvd7},{data:trt, addr:po 887},{data:trhd, addr:po 8798787}]
```

my resultant array that I want is,

```
let rslt =[data:tert, addr:po8798fvd7},{data:trhd, addr:po 8798787}]
```

that is in arr the object 'name' which is also in arr1 with name 'data' I don't need that array. nd some of which contain more than one name. I want to filter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
let arr=[{name:'trt,tet', id:5},{name:'td', id:25},{name:'fxg', id:1},{name:'fs', id:4},{name:'ste', id:41}]
let arr1 =[{data:'fxg', addr:'po 87987'},{data:'tert', addr:'po8798fvd7'},{data:'trt', addr:'po 887'},{data:'trhd', addr:'po 8798787'}]


const names = arr.flatMap(a => a.name.split(','))

const res = arr1.filter(a => !names.includes(a.data))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.. But I have one more doubt.. I updated my question. Please  check it

Answer (score 0):

This uses a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which is optimized for lookups in `O(1)` and therefore the runtime of the algorithm is `O(n)` in contrast to using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which will result in a runtime of `O(n²)`.

```js
let arr = [
  { name: "trt", id: 5 },
  { name: "td", id: 25 },
  { name: "fxg", id: 1 },
  { name: "fs", id: 4 },
  { name: "ste", id: 41 },
];

let arr1 = [
  { data: "fxg", addr: "po87987" },
  { data: "tert", addr: "po8798fvd7" },
  { data: "trt", addr: "po887" },
  { data: "trhd", addr: "po8798787" },
];

// use array for quick lookups in O(1)
const set = new Set(arr.map(item => item.name));

// filter arr1 adding only items to result that are not in Set
const result = arr1.filter(item => !set.has(item.data))
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```